# Convert often repeated code into a module

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub btnStatistics_click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim strPasswd As String
strPasswd = InputBox("Please Enter Password", "Password Required")

If strPasswd = Format(Now, "Hh") * 2 Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCustomer", acSaveYes
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStatistics", acNormal, "", "", acEdit, acNormal
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Incorrect password!", vbOKOnly, "Password Info"
End If

Exit_This_Sub:
    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub
```

I am using this VBA code in many buttons in different forms to do different things. I want to move the part `strPasswd = Format(Now, "Hh") * 2` into a module so I can update/change it in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is only the test of the password that you want to move, create a `Function` that returns a `Boolean`:

```
Function PasswordOK(strPwd As String) As Boolean
    PasswordOK = strPwd = Format(Now, "Hh") * 2
End Function
```

and then you can use it as:

```
If PasswordOK(strPasswd) Then
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCustomer", acSaveYes
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStatistics", acNormal, "", "", acEdit, acNormal
   'Exit Sub '<-- this isn't needed, because the next
             '    statement after this one is also Exit Sub
Else
   MsgBox "Incorrect password!", vbOKOnly, "Password Info"
End If
```

---

Or, if appropriate, you could move even more of the code into the common routine by passing a few more parameters:

```
Sub ChangeForm(oldForm As String, newForm As String)
    Dim strPasswd As String
    strPasswd = InputBox("Please Enter Password", "Password Required")

    If strPasswd = Format(Now, "Hh") * 2 Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, oldForm, acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenForm newForm, acNormal, "", "", acEdit, acNormal
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect password!", vbOKOnly, "Password Info"
    End If
End Sub
```

and use it as

```
Private Sub btnStatistics_click()
    ChangeForm "frmCustomer", "frmStatistics"
End Sub
```

---

Or perhaps somewhere between the two, putting just the input of the password, and its testing, into the common routine:

```
Function PasswordOK() As Boolean
    Dim strPasswd As String
    strPasswd = InputBox("Please Enter Password", "Password Required")
    If strPasswd = Format(Now, "Hh") * 2 Then
        PasswordOK = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect password!", vbOKOnly, "Password Info"
        PasswordOK = False
    End If
End Function
```

and use it as

```
Private Sub btnStatistics_click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

If PasswordOK() Then
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCustomer", acSaveYes
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStatistics", acNormal, "", "", acEdit, acNormal
End If

Exit_This_Sub:
   Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
   MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the first one is OK. Because different commands run each time.

Comment: Sorry. I tested it and it is working fine. Do I have to leave `Dim strPasswd As String` and `strPasswd = InputBox("Please Enter Password", "Password Required")` ?

Comment: @YvetteLee If you are using the first method (where only the testing of the password is done in the function) then you still need to input the password in your main code.  I'll update my answer to add a 3rd method which does the input and test, but not the rest.